# Going back in/to/from my past

Tags: prepositions

> ''I don't want to go back **to/from/in** my dark past.''

Let's say this example was an unpleasant period. What is the correct preposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to word this given the options is *"I don't want to go back **to** my dark past"*, because the goal is to convey that it would be a *step backward* or a progression towards something uncomfortable or unpleasant. The word *from* doesn't make sense in this context -- it implies that you'd be going away from it.

The option *in* is interesting, because while it doesn't work by itself, you could change to *into*, which conveys the same journey as implied in the *to* example. It's not as mechanically nice sounding, but it does convey the same idea. For example:

> I don't want to go back into my dark past.

Answer (score 1):

I have come **from** a dark past. I don't want to go back **to** my dark past.

> "Go back **from** my"

is just *plain wrong.* (Don't ask why :D)

> "Go back **to** my"

is implying going backwards, which is your goal.

And

> "Go back **in** my"

is like stepping "**Inside the dark**", which is not what you want either.

Also,
Like ***hakusaro*** said, **into** is something rarely spoken, but grammatically correct.